# idea Quarkus.run(args) not work, quarkus 1.6.0

Tags: java, quarkus

I follow the guides [QUARKUS - APPLICATION INITIALIZATION AND TERMINATION]https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle.
It not work when i right click the main method, and select Run 'Main.main()' id IDEA.
It throws :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at io.quarkus.launcher.QuarkusLauncher.launch(QuarkusLauncher.java:50)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.launchFromIDE(Quarkus.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:38)
    at com.haoyoungde.run.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.launcher.QuarkusLauncher.launch(QuarkusLauncher.java:47)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for null
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.IDELauncherImpl.launch(IDELauncherImpl.java:30)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to create the application model for null
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapAppModelFactory.resolveAppModel(BootstrapAppModelFactory.java:313)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.QuarkusBootstrap.bootstrap(QuarkusBootstrap.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.IDELauncherImpl.launch(IDELauncherImpl.java:27)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to determine the Maven artifact associated with the application /home/house/IdeaProjects/quarkus-learning/quarkus-application-run/target/classes
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapAppModelFactory.resolveAppModel(BootstrapAppModelFactory.java:253)
    ... 11 more
```

here is my code:

```
@QuarkusMain  
public class Main {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("Running main method");
        Quarkus.run(args); 
    }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What command exactly are you running?

Comment: right click the main method, select Run 'Main.main()' in idea

Comment: From the link you mentioned: `Run the application with: ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`. Does that work?

Comment: There is an official guide on using quarkus in IDEA btw: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/quarkus.html

Comment: I want to start the program like springboot via main method in idea, not use command string.

Comment: That's not how quarkus works.